# How to send mail with attachments in Plone using a template approach?

Tags: email, plone

I've been reading the [official docs](http://collective-docs.plone.org/misc/email.html) about sending emails from Plone using some templates, and it's working so far.

My question is: how do I add attachments using the template approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MailHost.send` command takes both python (unicode) strings and `email.Message` objects. That means you can use the [python email package](http://docs.python.org/library/email) to construct a proper MIME message with attachments.

The standard library includes [a great page of examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html); any text can still be generated by templates just like in the documentation you linked.

Comment: Pieters: I know it's possible to use the Python email package, but I liked the template (*.pt) approach because I'm sending some emails with html markup, and I would like to separate the email logic from the presentation: the problem is that I create all the headers manually on the pt file. How could I use the standard email package AND the pt approach, since I set the headers on the pt?

Comment: You can still use the message_from_string method to create email Message objects to use in a multi-part message construction.

Comment: Hum, do you think I can have a message.pt and an attachment.pt, and for each attachment, I concatenate the attachment.pt to my rendered message.pt?

Comment: When I do `mail_template = portal.mail_template_id
mail_text = mail_template`, I receive a unicode object. What defines the encoding, my system, a property? I'm having problems when sending non-ascii emails...

Answer (score 3):

Use Python's email module.

Examples:

http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

The composed messages can be passed to context.MailHost (the MTA of Zope).

It is in every case better generating and sending out emails from the Python level instead of using the old DTML sendmail facade...don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, maybe it is not the best:

create a mime_file DTML Method in portal_skin/custom:

```
  <dtml-mime type="text/text; charset=utf-8" encode="7bit">

  <dtml-var "text">

  <dtml-boundary type="application/octet-stream" disposition="attachment" 
  filename_expr="nomefile"><dtml-var "file"></dtml-mime>
```

Call it (for example from a Python Script) as:

```
message = context.mime_file(file=a_file, text=message, nomefile='attach_name.pdf')
context.MailHost.send(message, mTo, mFrom, mSubj)
```

where a_file is the content of the file.

inspired by:

http://www.zope.org/Members/visibleoffice/HowTo.2003-10-22.1455

This is a quick&dirt solution, using Python Scripts.

Comment: A modern approach require to build the mail body using a python library to handle mime and create the body with attach.